# Can this java application run on Heroku?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, heroku, java-metro-framework

I have no experience setting up java applications and no experience with Heroku but I have this java application I would like to know if I can easily run on Heroku.

https://github.com/difi/oxalis is the github repo and here is some install instructions for a standalone server:

- make sure that Maven is installed.
- make sure that Tomcat 7 and Metro 2.1.1 are installed
- make sure that the Tomcat manager is available on port 8080 with user manager/manager
- make sure that Tomcat is also up
  and running on SSL at localhost:8443
- make sure that keystore.jks is
  installed in a known directory (separate instructions for
  constructing the keystore)
- change
  oxalis-commons/src/main/filters/soc.properties to reflect your local
  preferences

Is this possible to set up on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it should run on Heroku but a few changes might be necessary.  You will not need to run Tomcat with SSL since Heroku provides the HTTPS in front of the Tomcat app.  You will probably have to update the Maven build to [pull in Tomcat via webapp-runner](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner).  The properties file should probably be replaced with [Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).  The only part that seems like it might be tricky is the Metro piece.  It's not clear how Metro is being pulled into the system and used.